# UItableview inside a view based application

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4

I have a view based application and a UITableview in the view.
I set the dataSource , delegate and tableView to "File's Owner"  when i click on the tableview
then clicking on the Files owner i set the tableView to Table View , view to View , datasource to Table View and delegate to Table view in the outlets.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)videoView {

    return 1;

}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.

- (NSInteger)videoView:(UITableView *)videoView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 0;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

- (UITableViewCell *)videoView:(UITableView *)videoView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [videoView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    // Set up the cell...
    return cell;

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)videoView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

when i run the application for the simulator i get the following error 
"tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6029710
"

i get the feeling that tableviews require different implementation when used in view based app rather than a navigation based application. I would be very thankful if anyone can guide me to what needs to be done to get this displayed properly.thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a delegate implementation you can't change tableView to videoView.  Should be:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 0;
}
```

You need to fix the other cellForRowAtIndexPath as well!

Comment: Great -- please do mark whichever answer you like best with the checkmark :)

Answer (score 2):

The implementation is the same whether you are in a view-based or navigation-based application. What this error message is telling you is your table view tried to call `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` on its data source, but that the data source didn't implement a method with that name. Sure enough, looking at your sample code, you implement a method called `videoView:numberOfRowsInSection:` instead of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Comment: Thank you ... that seemed to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

> I set the dataSource , delegate and tableView to "File's Owner" when i
>   click on the tableview then clicking on the Files owner i set the
>   tableView to Table View , view to View , datasource to Table View and
>   delegate to Table view in the outlets.

It's difficult to understand what you've done here. You set the table's data source to the table view itself?

> when i run the application for the simulator i get the following error
>   "tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x6029710 "

What object is at address 0x6029710? It's surely the object that you set as the table's data source, but it doesn't implement the UITableViewDataSource protocol.

> i get the feeling that tableviews require different implementation
>   when used in view based app rather than a navigation based
>   application.

There's really no difference between a "view based app" and a "navigation based app." There are "view based" and "nav based" project templates, but those are just two different starting points for your app. UITableView doesn't care which one you use.